# Strange happening on Fragment saving view states

Tags: android, lifecycle, fragment

Fragment A has a ListView. And I scroll it.
When the fragment A is replaced by fragment B (different Fragment) and added to back stack, and I press back button, fragment A has its previous scroll position.
This is really strange because OnCreateView on fragment A is called and new ListView is inflated. (of course the previous listview should be destroyed when the fragment B replaced fragment A)
More strange thing is... when I do this repeatedly for many times, by the chance of about 1/10, the scroll position is at the top.

I don't know wth is happening here... please give me an explanation.....

Comment: I'm answering this(my) question.

Someone on irc said that states are saved and restored by matching id or tags. (this was his guess, but probably right)
But I couldn't figure out why it loses the states in some probability.